# Spring Batch Process Indicator Pattern

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In a Spring Batch Job I am writing the item to target file (using FlatFileItemWriter) and updating input record "process indicator" field as "processed"/"failed" (using JdbcBatchItemWriter). Which is the best way to make this happen in a "item transaction" ?

1. Using a  CompositeItemWriter (delegates FlatFileItemWriter for
   writing to file and JdbcBatchItemWriter to update the "process
   indicator"
2. Using ItemWriteListener methods "afterWrite" and "onWriteError" to update the   "process indicator"

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way is to use the ChunkListener#afterChunk to update a flag like that.  This allows it to be separate from any retry, etc logic that gets involved in the other two options you proposed.

Comment: But how do you identify the processed items in a `ChunkListener`? The `afterChunk` method is parameterless and therefore doesn't inject the items like the `ItemWriteListener`.

Comment: While true, typically what you'd do is use the ChunkListener#beforeChunk() to flag the items to be processed.  Then the ChunkListener#afterChunk() flags them as processed once the chunk has completed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it: `ChunkListener#beforeChunk()` is parameterless, too. How can I identify the items to be processed from within the ChunkListener? The chunk can have multiple items, but they aren't injected into the Listener.

Comment: It would be the ChunkListener's responsibility to identify the next chunk of items to work on.  Say for example, you have a commit interval of 10 and the reader's query is:
select * from foo order by id where pf = 'In Process';
Your ChunkListener#beforeChunk() would update the rows returned by:
select * from foo order by id where process_flag is null limit 10;
Once you've updated the rows there, your reader/processor/writer would process the rows tagged by the listener.  Once the chunk committed, you would update the rows returned by:
select * from foo where pf = 'In Process';