# Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring-batch

We have two tables. In one table, data keep on inserting from different sources.

Requirement is, we need to read the records from that table and copy them into another table. Only those records which are not read previously by the batch program should be read and insert the records to another table.

We thought of using the `Spring Batch` running periodically. Batch will run periodically (every 10 mins) and copy the data (only those records which are not copied to another table) from that table and insert into another table.

My question is, if a batch process picks 100 records at a time how another instance of batch process (if two instances run of a batch job) knows a set of records are already been picked up from DB? And in case of failure happens while copying the data how should I handle that scenario.

Comment: You have to handle the "lock" or have a kind of orchestrator giving data to your instances. You can also make your batch jobs idempotent if possible. This way, even if two instances process the same line, it does not matter.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more.. what is the way to prevent read data which was already read in database by one instance of batch job without having flag column in table... What is the best possible way to handle these types of scenario though spring batch.

Comment: In the query for reader, could you put a logic to ignore ID(s) processed? My assumption is same ID migrated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch Process Indicator Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503993/spring-batch-process-indicator-pattern)