# Starting a new job instance with last processed record as jobParameter in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

We are working on a Spring Batch job. The job will run everyday for about ~6 hours and will fetch some value, corresponding to each record, from a REST service. Once the value is retrieved from the REST service, it's updated for the corresponding record. For e.g.

```
--------------------
   Student
--------------------
Id | Name | Marks
--------------------
1  | John | Null
2  | Sam  | Null
3  | Lilly| Null
```

Iterate over each record(`ASC` order) and fetch the Marks from REST service based on `Id`. Update the column Marks with the marks retrieved. The REST service does not support batch operations and can only handle one record at a time.

**Proposed Solution:**

1. Read data from db using a `RepositoryItemReader` using a fixed page size in ASC order. Since by default there is no range of Ids the job will continue to run forever( will be stopped after ~6 hours everyday).
2. Call a REST service to fetch marks based on each record `Id` and update Student object with marks. (CustomItemProcessor)
3. Update the student object using `RepositoryItemWriter`.

**Problems that need to be resolved:**

There are 2 problems:

1.**Need to know the last processed record to resume from there** (we would like
to create a new job instance everyday).
In order to run the job everyday, we can benchmark the job and estimate the
number of records it will process everyday. Based on that we can define Id
ranges in a static Table so that the job reads range from the table and
processes records within the range. This solution is not very elegant.
Another approach would be to store the last fetched( not read) in a tracking
table and use it as lower limit for the next day. I am not sure how can I
achieve this elegantly.

2.**Improve performance of the job**
In a single thread sequential mode, the performance is not very good. It's only
able to process 1 record/ 2 seconds ( 0.5 record/ second). I used a
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with a thread pool size of around 10 and was able to
achieve a performance of 4 records/ sec (which is ideal for us).

Comment: Why don't you write the last processed it to the database and then select it pass it as a parameter?

Comment: yes , I was thinking the same , but when should I write the last processed record? @AfterJob? Is it possible to get this information from the Job Execution context? As i mentioned since it's multithreaded, the last processed record isn't necessarily the max id from the records fetched for read.

Answer (score 0):

> Since we are also using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, it's not straightforward to know the last processed record.

Ordering is not compatible with multi-threading. "First" and "Last" are undefined if you go parallel. You need to find a way to mark records in a way that is agnostic from a serial or a parallel execution. I highly recommend to first find a correct solution to the problem before introducing multi-threading: correctness is more important than performance.

> We want to run a new Job instance everyday.

This means that the current date is a good candidate for an identifying job parameter.

Comment: I understand. Does it mean there is no way to use any sort of parallelism in this case? I understand it may not be possible to do it once you split the chunks, but is it possible while you read the page? We were thinking of using RepositoryItemReader and reading input with a certain page size. if we can get the max id from the page while reading, we can store it in a custom table.

Comment: `Does it mean there is no way to use any sort of parallelism in this case?`: You did not share any correct solution that is single threaded to be able to tell you if there is a way to parallelize it or not. What I'm expecting in your description is something like: "Here is a solution that works for my problem, but is a slow and I want to improve its performance. How to do that?" . This is what I mentioned about correctness in my answer.

Comment: I recommend to first describe the problem at hand without referring to Spring Batch. Does your step 3 modify the input records? Is there a column to track that? A concrete example with the complete flow for one record would help.

Comment: I have added more details. I hope I was able to explain my problem now.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. For problem 1: `Need to know the last processed record to resume from there (we would like to create a new job instance everyday)`: Why is that? I see nothing that changes from day to day in your input. You need to design each job instance to process a fixed dataset (which is represented by identifying job parameters). It is not clear from your description and updates what represents a job instance. For problem 2, a multi-threaded step or a partitioned step are both good options, as long as problem 1 is correctly solved first.

Comment: Let's say there are 10000 records in the table and the job can only process ~ 500 records everyday in 6 hours. We would like it to resume from the 501st record the next day. We can achieve this by either providing the id range as job parameter manually for. e.g
Day 1 - 1-500
Day 2 - 501 -1000 etc 
Or let Job save the state automatically and resume from there. We wanted to to understand if it's possible to do it automatically.

Comment: You seem to want to design job instances based on time windows and not on fixed datasets. This is what really creates Problem 1, ie the design itself. If you really want to base your current execution on information from the last execution (like the last processed record), you can use the `JobExplorer` to get the last job/step execution and check the read/write counts. Then you increment the the last read count and pass it a job parameter to the current job to start reading from there. This might work, but I don't see how you would handle failure in the previous run.

Comment: Another technique is to use the process indicator pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503993/spring-batch-process-indicator-pattern, which requires an additional column in your table and two additional queries on each execution to identify and mark records.. So it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I explored the `JobExplorer` option as well as the `process indicator pattern`. The `JobExplorer` won't work because it assumes all Id's are deleted. If they are deleted Total commit + 1 != next execution id.
The problem with process indicator pattern(link shared above) is that it assumes all chunks are processed sequentially and the last chunk processed has the largest set of ids. I may be wrong but it does not seem suitable for a multithreaded scenario.
I thought about it and this is what I propose.

Comment: 1. Read the max id from the last page read
   To achieve this override the RepositoryItemReader.doPageRead() method. Get max id 
   maxIdObject = results.get(results.size() - 1).
2. Threadpool processes multipel chunks from this.
3. @AfterStep, save the maxIdObject in a new column table.
4.  Read and repeat.

In case of failure , at max only 1 page worth of records will be reprocessed, which is fine.
2/2

Comment: Sounds really dirty , but does address all the concerns.

Comment: In my first comment after your last comment, read it as "The JobExplorer won't work because it assumes no Id's are deleted"